# Как вывести все процессы одним сообщением?

Tags: python

Имеется следующий код, как вывести в нем все процессы одним сообщением и убрать из каждого .exe?

```
import psutil
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    name = proc.name()
    print(name)
    if name == "program.exe":
        pass
```

Чтобы получилось:

```
chrome
opera
browser
svhost
....
```

Comment: Вы понимаете как работает этот код? А в "чтобы получилось" у вас не одним сообщением, а разными.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Способов можно придумать море

Вот этот почти правильный (почти потому что на некоторых системах приложения без расширений и может быть точка в имени)

```
name = proc.name().rsplit('.',maxsplit=1)[0]
```

Вот этот не очень, но

```
name = proc.name().rstrip('ex').strip('.')
```

Одним сообщением это как? предположу что

```
proclist = list(map( lambda proc:  proc.name().rsplit('.',maxsplit=1)[0]
, psutil.process_iter()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Через `subprocess` можно:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

prs = Popen('tasklist', stdout=PIPE).stdout.readlines()
pr_list = [prs[i].decode('cp866', 'ignore').split()[0] for i in range(3,len(prs))]

for p in pr_list:
    print(p.split('.exe')[0])
```

Для получения одной строки из списка:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

prs = Popen('tasklist', stdout=PIPE).stdout.readlines()
pr_list = [prs[i].decode('cp866', 'ignore').split()[0].split('.exe')[0] for i in range(3,len(prs))]
pr_string = ', '.join(pr_list)

print(pr_string)
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, этот способ хорошо годится. Только как сделать вывод процессов в один абзац? Чтобы полученный результат не разделялся, а был как одно целое

Comment: @blox Добавил в ответ